# Prove that $EFZY$ is a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

> The incircle of $ABC$ touches $BC, CA,$ and $AB$ at $D, E,$ and $F$ respectively. $X$ is a point inside $ABC$ such that the incircle of $XBC$ touches $BC$ at $D$ also, and touches $CX$ and $XB$ at $Y$ and $Z$, respectively. Prove that $EFZY$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

**Picture**

[image]

**Solution**
[image]

**Question**

I get how the position of $P$ does not depend on $A$, but how does that mean that $YZ$ passes through $P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, run their Menelaus proof backwards. Apply the converse of Menelaus theorem to $\Delta XBC$ and points $Z,Y,P$:

$$\frac{XY}{YC}\cdot \frac{CP}{PB}\cdot \frac{BZ}{ZX}=$$
$$\frac{1}{YC}\cdot \frac{CP}{PB}\cdot \frac{BZ}{1}=$$
$$\frac{1}{YC}\cdot \frac{CP}{PB}\cdot \frac{BD}{1}=$$
$$\frac{1}{CD}\cdot \frac{CP}{PB}\cdot \frac{BD}{1}=$$
$$\frac{1}{CD}\cdot \frac{DC}{BD}\cdot \frac{BD}{1}=1$$
where in the last step I used $BP/CP=BD/DC$ as derived in the given solution.

Comment: How does that prove that how does that mean that $YZ$ passes through $P$?

Comment: @user19405892 I had a typo (which I fixed): apply menelaus to points Z,Y, P (I had previously written Z,Y,D). The converse to menelaus says that if the product of three ratios equals 1 (ignoring signs), then Z,Y,P are collinear, i.e. YZ passes thru P. So that's why I computed that the product of the three ratios equals 1.

Answer (score 0):

If the position of $P$ does not depend on $A$ but only on the position of $D$, then moving $A$ to $X$ won't change the intersection between line $BC$ and the line passing through the other two tangency points.